# Trouble with Appodeal Rewarded Video

Tags: android, appodeal

I'm having some problems with `Appodeal rewarded Videos`, actually, the problem is not with appodeal but with some network, and I can not find out what is. My app exhib the video normally, however the `onRewardedVideoFinished()` method sometimes is not called and sometimes is (this way the reward is not given and the user, at sure, will be very pissed off).

I realized that the videos that did not called the method came from a same place, 'cause they are often the same video and have the particularity of do not have a time to inform the user when they will finish.

I'm trying to find out what is this network in order to disable it... But all that I got in LogCat was this:

```
05-02 10:22:38.934 6035-6352/? I/Ads: Trying mediation network: 
05-02 10:22:38.936 6035-6035/? I/Ads: Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.DummyAdapter
05-02 10:22:38.939 6035-6352/? I/Ads: No fill from any mediation ad networks.
05-02 10:22:38.939 6035-6035/? W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
05-02 10:22:38.960 6035-6035/? I/Ads: Starting ad request.
05-02 10:22:38.961 6035-6035/? I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("43DF75756E9C485BD0143D65AC613F73") to get test ads on this device.
05-02 10:22:39.025 1216-6248/? W/Ads: App does not have the required permissions to get location
```

Someone already had a same problem? And you found out what is the network that did this?

**Note** - my app is not a test, and already was published. All the others ads work, include others videos... Just have 1 or 2 videos that don't... and I need to find out what is the network that is send them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out which network is causing this issue enable debug logging

```
Appodeal.setLogLevel(com.appodeal.ads.utils.Log.LogLevel.debug)
```

After that you'll see logs like this one in your logcat when rewarded video ad is shown:

```
D/Appodeal: {network_name} onRewardedVideoShown
```

To disable the network call

```
Appodeal.disableNetwork((Activity) this, "network_name", Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO)
```

before Appodeal SDK initialization

Comment: Thx, I used this and could see that had no any problem with Appodeal, the problem was that each time that some screen (like videos) came on top of my app screen, the Android, I don't know why, called the onDestroy() before the prize will be save, this way when the other screen go off, my app was restarted calling onCreate() again... and nothing worked. Really Thx

Comment: Just one more question, I was able to notice that the largest eCPM ads are not loading, the smaller eCPM ads are. I know this is not Appodeal's problem, because the same thing happened with Admob, but you know why this happens? Does it have to do with the networks' interest in the app? When the app has more users can this stop happening? I'm new to this ... Thx

Comment: High eCPM ads fill very rarely. Whether ad is filled or not depends on many factors, including, but not limited to, country and location of the user, quality and type(game or application) of the app and many more.